# ptrace not recording forked process despite setting PTRACE_SETOPTIONS to PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK

Tags: c, fork, ptrace

I'm trying to follow the syscalls of a program using ptrace, but it does not work when the traced program has a fork() and just ignores it, supposedly you just need to set the line below and it should follow the process originating from fork() as well.

> ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK);
> I'm posting my code below, for tracer.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <program> [args...]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t child;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    int status;
    int notPrinted = 1;

    child = fork();

    if (child == 0){
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) < 0){
            perror("ptrace");
            return 1;
        }
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    }
    else if (child > 0){
        wait(&status);

        ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, NULL, PTRACE_SETOPTIONS | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD);
        while (WIFSTOPPED(status)){
            ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);

            if(notPrinted){
                if (regs.orig_rax != -1){
                    notPrinted = 0;
                    printf("FROM: %d, Syscall %ld: rdi=%ld, rsi=%ld, rdx=%ld, r10=%ld\n",
                        child, regs.orig_rax, regs.rbx, regs.rcx, regs.rdx, regs.r10);
                }
            }
            else{
                notPrinted = 1;
            }
            if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL) < 0){
                perror("ptrace");
                return 1;
            }
            wait(&status);
        }
    }
    else{
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As well as a simple program I've been using to test, random.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    if(fork() == 0){
        sleep(1);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf("%d ", rand() & 0xf);
    }
    printf("\n");
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Previously I had the following line with just set option to "PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK"; So i believe the issue is still a wrong configuration of PTRACE_SETOPTIONS; my goal is to have the program follow a program that uses fork() correctly, like strace -f option does

> ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, NULL, PTRACE_SETOPTIONS | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD);

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <program> [args...]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t child;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    int status;

    child = fork();

    if (child == 0){
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("ptrace");
            return 1;
        }
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    } else if (child > 0){
        child = wait(&status);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, NULL, PTRACE_SETOPTIONS | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);

        while (WIFSTOPPED(status)){
            ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);

            if (regs.orig_rax != -1){
                printf("FROM: %d, Syscall %ld: rdi=%ld, rsi=%ld, rdx=%ld, r10=%ld\n",
                        child, regs.orig_rax, regs.rbx, regs.rcx, regs.rdx, regs.r10);
            }
            if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL) < 0){
                perror("ptrace");
                return 1;
            }

            child = wait(&status);
        }
    } else{
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the new code with PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE option included, removed notPrinted just for code readability, and with updated child by doing

```
child = wait(&status);
ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
```

to get updated child, and then to read the registers from the process; But I'm still only getting one process as child, any idea why so?

Comment: Does [this address your need](https://pramode.net/articles/lfy/ptrace/pramode.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. You need to [also] add `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` when you set options. You're doing `fork` but that's the libc function. (e.g. Under linux) it uses the `clone` syscall).
2. You have to do `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);` to resume the child after the tracer processes the stop.
3. If you're going to trace an app that calls `fork` and you want to also trace any children it created, you have to use the correct pid. You never change the value of `child`, so you never get the `pid` of any grandchildren.
4. You have to do: `child = wait(&status);` When you're tracing multiple children, you have to know *which* pid caused the return from `wait`.

---

For some additional info, you could look at some of my `ptrace` answers:

1. [Ptrace options not working in parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72620471/5382650)

---

**UPDATE:**

> I have edited the code if you could please check again. I have added PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE, I did not add ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0); because I believe ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL) already does that and PTRACE_CONT is not required, and changed to record child_pid, but im not getting the grandchild, any ideas on what else I can do? –
> frazz

Yes, `PTRACE_SYSCALL` is sufficient.

I reworked your latest source. In the process, I discovered the bug.

Your `PTRACE_SETOPTIONS` call is incorrect. You are doing:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_SETOPTIONS |
    PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
```

You are ORing in `PTRACE_SETOPTIONS` into the last argument. This argument should *only* have `PTRACE_O_*` options in it.

This [somehow] breaks things. The correct way is:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK |
    PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
```

I added some extra code to have a per-process control struct to keep track of the state of each process being traced. While not strictly necessary for your example, it is a common thing to do.

I also added a log file for tracing.

And, I refactored your `random` a bit to be slightly more trace friendly (not necessary but helped spot the issue).

Here is the tracer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <syscall.h>

FILE *xflog;
int opt_bug;                                // 1=show bug
int opt_v;                                  // 1=verbose dump mode
char *opt_L;                                // logfile name
char *pgmname;

#define logf(_fmt...) \
    fprintf(xflog,_fmt)

#if 0
#define DREG(_reg) \
    logf(" " #_reg "=%16.16llX/%llu\n",regs._reg,regs._reg)
#else
#define DREG(_reg) \
    logf(" " #_reg "=%16.16llX\n",regs._reg)
#endif

struct pidctl {
    struct pidctl *ctl_next;                // linked list
    pid_t ctl_pid;                          // process id
    int ctl_xid;                            // incremental id (e.g. 1, 2, 3)
    unsigned int ctl_seqno;                 // event sequence number
    int ctl_status;                         // status from last wait call
    int ctl_signo;                          // signal number from last call
    int ctl_mode;                           // mode (0=enter, 1=exit) syscall
};

struct pidctl *pidlist;                     // list of active processes
int pidcount;                               // number of entries in pidlist
int pidxid;                                 // incremental id

#if 1
#define WAITFOR(_status)        wait(_status)
#else
#define WAITFOR(_status)        waitpid(-1,_status,0)
#endif

const char *sysname(int sysno);

// pidfind -- find control for given pid
struct pidctl *
pidfind(pid_t pid,int status)
{
    struct pidctl *prev = NULL;
    struct pidctl *cur = pidlist;

    // find existing entry
    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->ctl_next) {
        if (cur->ctl_pid == pid)
            break;
        prev = cur;
    }

    do {
        // already exists
        if (cur != NULL)
            break;

        // create new entry
        cur = calloc(1,sizeof(*cur));
        cur->ctl_pid = pid;
        cur->ctl_xid = pidxid++;
        logf("pidfind: NEWPID ctl_xid=%d ctl_pid=%8.8X/%d\n",
            cur->ctl_xid,cur->ctl_pid,cur->ctl_pid);

        // start in "AFT" mode
        cur->ctl_mode = 1;

        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->ctl_next = cur;
        else
            pidlist = cur;

        ++pidcount;
    } while (0);

    cur->ctl_status = status;

    if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
        cur->ctl_signo = WSTOPSIG(status);
    else
        cur->ctl_signo = 0;

    return cur;
}

void
pidsetup(pid_t pid)
{

// NOTE/BUG: PTRACE_SETOPTIONS must _not_ be or'ed in with PTRACE_O_*
    if (opt_bug)
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_SETOPTIONS |
            PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
    else
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK |
            PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    pgmname = *argv;
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'b':
            opt_bug = ! opt_bug;
            break;
        case 'v':
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        case 'L':
            opt_L = (*cp != 0) ? cp : NULL;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc < 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s <program> [args...]\n", pgmname);
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t child;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    int status;

    if (opt_L == NULL)
        opt_L = "LOG";
    xflog = fopen(opt_L,"w");
    setlinebuf(xflog);

    child = fork();
    if (child < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if (child == 0) {
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("ptrace");
            return 1;
        }
        execvp(argv[0], &argv[0]);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(9);
    }

    struct pidctl *ctl;

    child = WAITFOR(&status);

#if 1
    ctl = pidfind(child,status);
#endif

    pidsetup(child);

    unsigned int seqno = 0;
    int sysno;
    int exit_count = 0;

    while (pidcount > 0) {
        logf("\n");
        ctl = pidfind(child,status);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            logf("EXIT: %d status=%8.8X\n",ctl->ctl_xid,status);
            --pidcount;
            if (pidcount <= 0)
                break;
            continue;
        }

        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);

        sysno = regs.orig_rax;

        do {
#if 0
            if (sysno == -1)
                break;
#endif

#if 0
            logf("FROM: %d, Syscall %ld: rdi=%ld, rsi=%ld, rdx=%ld, r10=%ld\n",
                child, regs.orig_rax, regs.rbx, regs.rcx, regs.rdx, regs.r10);
#else
            logf("%u: %d %s %d/%s\n",
                seqno,ctl->ctl_xid,
                ctl->ctl_mode ? "AFT" : "BEF",
                sysno,sysname(sysno));
            if (opt_v) {
                DREG(rdi);
                DREG(rsi);
                DREG(rdx);
                DREG(rcx);
                DREG(r10);
            }
            DREG(rax);
#endif
        } while (0);

        // wait for exit from all ones we're tracing
        if (sysno == __NR_exit_group) {
            if (++exit_count == pidcount)
                break;
        }

        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("ptrace");
            return 1;
        }

        ctl->ctl_seqno = seqno++;
        ctl->ctl_mode = ! ctl->ctl_mode;

        child = WAITFOR(&status);
    }

    fclose(xflog);

    return 0;
}

#define NRALL(_cmd) \
    _cmd(read) \
    _cmd(write) \
    _cmd(open) \
    _cmd(close) \
    _cmd(stat) \
    _cmd(fstat) \
    _cmd(lstat) \
    _cmd(poll) \
    _cmd(lseek) \
    _cmd(mmap) \
    _cmd(mprotect) \
    _cmd(munmap) \
    _cmd(brk) \
    _cmd(rt_sigaction) \
    _cmd(rt_sigprocmask) \
    _cmd(rt_sigreturn) \
    _cmd(ioctl) \
    _cmd(pread64) \
    _cmd(pwrite64) \
    _cmd(readv) \
    _cmd(writev) \
    _cmd(access) \
    _cmd(pipe) \
    _cmd(select) \
    _cmd(sched_yield) \
    _cmd(mremap) \
    _cmd(msync) \
    _cmd(mincore) \
    _cmd(madvise) \
    _cmd(shmget) \
    _cmd(shmat) \
    _cmd(shmctl) \
    _cmd(dup) \
    _cmd(dup2) \
    _cmd(pause) \
    _cmd(nanosleep) \
    _cmd(getitimer) \
    _cmd(alarm) \
    _cmd(setitimer) \
    _cmd(getpid) \
    _cmd(sendfile) \
    _cmd(socket) \
    _cmd(connect) \
    _cmd(accept) \
    _cmd(sendto) \
    _cmd(recvfrom) \
    _cmd(sendmsg) \
    _cmd(recvmsg) \
    _cmd(shutdown) \
    _cmd(bind) \
    _cmd(listen) \
    _cmd(getsockname) \
    _cmd(getpeername) \
    _cmd(socketpair) \
    _cmd(setsockopt) \
    _cmd(getsockopt) \
    _cmd(clone) \
    _cmd(fork) \
    _cmd(vfork) \
    _cmd(execve) \
    _cmd(exit) \
    _cmd(wait4) \
    _cmd(kill) \
    _cmd(uname) \
    _cmd(semget) \
    _cmd(semop) \
    _cmd(semctl) \
    _cmd(shmdt) \
    _cmd(msgget) \
    _cmd(msgsnd) \
    _cmd(msgrcv) \
    _cmd(msgctl) \
    _cmd(fcntl) \
    _cmd(flock) \
    _cmd(fsync) \
    _cmd(fdatasync) \
    _cmd(truncate) \
    _cmd(ftruncate) \
    _cmd(getdents) \
    _cmd(getcwd) \
    _cmd(chdir) \
    _cmd(fchdir) \
    _cmd(rename) \
    _cmd(mkdir) \
    _cmd(rmdir) \
    _cmd(creat) \
    _cmd(link) \
    _cmd(unlink) \
    _cmd(symlink) \
    _cmd(readlink) \
    _cmd(chmod) \
    _cmd(fchmod) \
    _cmd(chown) \
    _cmd(fchown) \
    _cmd(lchown) \
    _cmd(umask) \
    _cmd(gettimeofday) \
    _cmd(getrlimit) \
    _cmd(getrusage) \
    _cmd(sysinfo) \
    _cmd(times) \
    _cmd(ptrace) \
    _cmd(getuid) \
    _cmd(syslog) \
    _cmd(getgid) \
    _cmd(setuid) \
    _cmd(setgid) \
    _cmd(geteuid) \
    _cmd(getegid) \
    _cmd(setpgid) \
    _cmd(getppid) \
    _cmd(getpgrp) \
    _cmd(setsid) \
    _cmd(setreuid) \
    _cmd(setregid) \
    _cmd(getgroups) \
    _cmd(setgroups) \
    _cmd(setresuid) \
    _cmd(getresuid) \
    _cmd(setresgid) \
    _cmd(getresgid) \
    _cmd(getpgid) \
    _cmd(setfsuid) \
    _cmd(setfsgid) \
    _cmd(getsid) \
    _cmd(capget) \
    _cmd(capset) \
    _cmd(rt_sigpending) \
    _cmd(rt_sigtimedwait) \
    _cmd(rt_sigqueueinfo) \
    _cmd(rt_sigsuspend) \
    _cmd(sigaltstack) \
    _cmd(utime) \
    _cmd(mknod) \
    _cmd(uselib) \
    _cmd(personality) \
    _cmd(ustat) \
    _cmd(statfs) \
    _cmd(fstatfs) \
    _cmd(sysfs) \
    _cmd(getpriority) \
    _cmd(setpriority) \
    _cmd(sched_setparam) \
    _cmd(sched_getparam) \
    _cmd(sched_setscheduler) \
    _cmd(sched_getscheduler) \
    _cmd(sched_get_priority_max) \
    _cmd(sched_get_priority_min) \
    _cmd(sched_rr_get_interval) \
    _cmd(mlock) \
    _cmd(munlock) \
    _cmd(mlockall) \
    _cmd(munlockall) \
    _cmd(vhangup) \
    _cmd(modify_ldt) \
    _cmd(pivot_root) \
    _cmd(_sysctl) \
    _cmd(prctl) \
    _cmd(arch_prctl) \
    _cmd(adjtimex) \
    _cmd(setrlimit) \
    _cmd(chroot) \
    _cmd(sync) \
    _cmd(acct) \
    _cmd(settimeofday) \
    _cmd(mount) \
    _cmd(umount2) \
    _cmd(swapon) \
    _cmd(swapoff) \
    _cmd(reboot) \
    _cmd(sethostname) \
    _cmd(setdomainname) \
    _cmd(iopl) \
    _cmd(ioperm) \
    _cmd(create_module) \
    _cmd(init_module) \
    _cmd(delete_module) \
    _cmd(get_kernel_syms) \
    _cmd(query_module) \
    _cmd(quotactl) \
    _cmd(nfsservctl) \
    _cmd(getpmsg) \
    _cmd(putpmsg) \
    _cmd(afs_syscall) \
    _cmd(tuxcall) \
    _cmd(security) \
    _cmd(gettid) \
    _cmd(readahead) \
    _cmd(setxattr) \
    _cmd(lsetxattr) \
    _cmd(fsetxattr) \
    _cmd(getxattr) \
    _cmd(lgetxattr) \
    _cmd(fgetxattr) \
    _cmd(listxattr) \
    _cmd(llistxattr) \
    _cmd(flistxattr) \
    _cmd(removexattr) \
    _cmd(lremovexattr) \
    _cmd(fremovexattr) \
    _cmd(tkill) \
    _cmd(time) \
    _cmd(futex) \
    _cmd(sched_setaffinity) \
    _cmd(sched_getaffinity) \
    _cmd(set_thread_area) \
    _cmd(io_setup) \
    _cmd(io_destroy) \
    _cmd(io_getevents) \
    _cmd(io_submit) \
    _cmd(io_cancel) \
    _cmd(get_thread_area) \
    _cmd(lookup_dcookie) \
    _cmd(epoll_create) \
    _cmd(epoll_ctl_old) \
    _cmd(epoll_wait_old) \
    _cmd(remap_file_pages) \
    _cmd(getdents64) \
    _cmd(set_tid_address) \
    _cmd(restart_syscall) \
    _cmd(semtimedop) \
    _cmd(fadvise64) \
    _cmd(timer_create) \
    _cmd(timer_settime) \
    _cmd(timer_gettime) \
    _cmd(timer_getoverrun) \
    _cmd(timer_delete) \
    _cmd(clock_settime) \
    _cmd(clock_gettime) \
    _cmd(clock_getres) \
    _cmd(clock_nanosleep) \
    _cmd(exit_group) \
    _cmd(epoll_wait) \
    _cmd(epoll_ctl) \
    _cmd(tgkill) \
    _cmd(utimes) \
    _cmd(vserver) \
    _cmd(mbind) \
    _cmd(set_mempolicy) \
    _cmd(get_mempolicy) \
    _cmd(mq_open) \
    _cmd(mq_unlink) \
    _cmd(mq_timedsend) \
    _cmd(mq_timedreceive) \
    _cmd(mq_notify) \
    _cmd(mq_getsetattr) \
    _cmd(kexec_load) \
    _cmd(waitid) \
    _cmd(add_key) \
    _cmd(request_key) \
    _cmd(keyctl) \
    _cmd(ioprio_set) \
    _cmd(ioprio_get) \
    _cmd(inotify_init) \
    _cmd(inotify_add_watch) \
    _cmd(inotify_rm_watch) \
    _cmd(migrate_pages) \
    _cmd(openat) \
    _cmd(mkdirat) \
    _cmd(mknodat) \
    _cmd(fchownat) \
    _cmd(futimesat) \
    _cmd(newfstatat) \
    _cmd(unlinkat) \
    _cmd(renameat) \
    _cmd(linkat) \
    _cmd(symlinkat) \
    _cmd(readlinkat) \
    _cmd(fchmodat) \
    _cmd(faccessat) \
    _cmd(pselect6) \
    _cmd(ppoll) \
    _cmd(unshare) \
    _cmd(set_robust_list) \
    _cmd(get_robust_list) \
    _cmd(splice) \
    _cmd(tee) \
    _cmd(sync_file_range) \
    _cmd(vmsplice) \
    _cmd(move_pages) \
    _cmd(utimensat) \
    _cmd(epoll_pwait) \
    _cmd(signalfd) \
    _cmd(timerfd_create) \
    _cmd(eventfd) \
    _cmd(fallocate) \
    _cmd(timerfd_settime) \
    _cmd(timerfd_gettime) \
    _cmd(accept4) \
    _cmd(signalfd4) \
    _cmd(eventfd2) \
    _cmd(epoll_create1) \
    _cmd(dup3) \
    _cmd(pipe2) \
    _cmd(inotify_init1) \
    _cmd(preadv) \
    _cmd(pwritev) \
    _cmd(rt_tgsigqueueinfo) \
    _cmd(perf_event_open) \
    _cmd(recvmmsg) \
    _cmd(fanotify_init) \
    _cmd(fanotify_mark) \
    _cmd(prlimit64) \
    _cmd(name_to_handle_at) \
    _cmd(open_by_handle_at) \
    _cmd(clock_adjtime) \
    _cmd(syncfs) \
    _cmd(sendmmsg) \
    _cmd(setns) \
    _cmd(getcpu) \
    _cmd(process_vm_readv) \
    _cmd(process_vm_writev) \
    _cmd(kcmp) \
    _cmd(finit_module) \
    _cmd(sched_setattr) \
    _cmd(sched_getattr) \
    _cmd(renameat2) \
    _cmd(seccomp) \
    _cmd(getrandom) \
    _cmd(memfd_create) \
    _cmd(kexec_file_load) \
    _cmd(bpf) \
    _cmd(execveat) \
    _cmd(userfaultfd) \
    _cmd(membarrier) \
    _cmd(mlock2) \
    _cmd(copy_file_range) \
    _cmd(preadv2) \
    _cmd(pwritev2) \
    _cmd(pkey_mprotect) \
    _cmd(pkey_alloc) \
    _cmd(pkey_free) \
    _cmd(statx) \
    _cmd(io_pgetevents) \
    _cmd(rseq) \
    _cmd(pidfd_send_signal) \
    _cmd(io_uring_setup) \
    _cmd(io_uring_enter) \
    _cmd(io_uring_register) \
    _cmd(open_tree) \
    _cmd(move_mount) \
    _cmd(fsopen) \
    _cmd(fsconfig) \
    _cmd(fsmount) \
    _cmd(fspick) \
    _cmd(pidfd_open) \
    _cmd(clone3)

#define NRSTR(_sym) \
    [__NR_##_sym] = #_sym,
const char *NR_name[] = {
    NRALL(NRSTR)
};

const char *
sysname(int sysno)
{

    return NR_name[sysno];
}
```

---

Here is the test program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int opt_w;                              // 1=wait for child

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'w':
            opt_w = ! opt_w;
            break;
        }
    }

    int xid = 0;

    pid_t child = fork();

    if (child == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        ++xid;
    }
    srand(time(NULL));

    pid_t pid = getpid();

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    printf("%d: pid=%d\n",xid,pid);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", xid, rand() & 0xf);
    }

    sleep(5);

    if (opt_w && (child != 0))
        wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the `LOG` file for the "buggy" case (e.g. `-b`). Notice that there is only one process traced and that there are *no* `clone` syscalls.

```
pidfind: NEWPID ctl_xid=0 ctl_pid=00150066/1376358

0: 0 AFT 59/execve
 rax=0000000000000000

1: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

2: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=000000000159F000

3: 0 BEF 158/arch_prctl
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

4: 0 AFT 158/arch_prctl
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFEA

5: 0 BEF 21/access
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

6: 0 AFT 21/access
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE

7: 0 BEF 257/openat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

8: 0 AFT 257/openat
 rax=0000000000000004

9: 0 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

10: 0 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

11: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

12: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DFE8000

13: 0 BEF 3/close
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

14: 0 AFT 3/close
 rax=0000000000000000

15: 0 BEF 257/openat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

16: 0 AFT 257/openat
 rax=0000000000000004

17: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

18: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000340

19: 0 BEF 8/lseek
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

20: 0 AFT 8/lseek
 rax=0000000000000318

21: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

22: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000044

23: 0 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

24: 0 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

25: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

26: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DFE6000

27: 0 BEF 8/lseek
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

28: 0 AFT 8/lseek
 rax=0000000000000318

29: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

30: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000044

31: 0 BEF 8/lseek
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

32: 0 AFT 8/lseek
 rax=0000000000000360

33: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

34: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000020

35: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

36: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DE20000

37: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

38: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

39: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

40: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DE42000

41: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

42: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DF8F000

43: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

44: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DFDC000

45: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

46: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FC42DFE2000

47: 0 BEF 3/close
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

48: 0 AFT 3/close
 rax=0000000000000000

49: 0 BEF 158/arch_prctl
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

50: 0 AFT 158/arch_prctl
 rax=0000000000000000

51: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

52: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

53: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

54: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

55: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

56: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

57: 0 BEF 11/munmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

58: 0 AFT 11/munmap
 rax=0000000000000000

59: 0 BEF 56/clone
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

60: 0 AFT 56/clone
 rax=0000000000150067

61: 0 BEF 39/getpid
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

62: 0 AFT 39/getpid
 rax=0000000000150066

63: 0 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

64: 0 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

65: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

66: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=000000000159F000

67: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

68: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=00000000015C0000

69: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

70: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=00000000015C0000

71: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

72: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=000000000000000F

73: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

74: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

75: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

76: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000006

77: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

78: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

79: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

80: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

81: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

82: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

83: 0 BEF 35/nanosleep
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

84: 0 AFT 35/nanosleep
 rax=0000000000000000

85: 0 BEF 231/exit_group
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA
```

---

Here is the `LOG` for the "fixed" case:

```
pidfind: NEWPID ctl_xid=0 ctl_pid=0015006B/1376363

0: 0 AFT 59/execve
 rax=0000000000000000

1: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

2: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F4D000

3: 0 BEF 158/arch_prctl
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

4: 0 AFT 158/arch_prctl
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFEA

5: 0 BEF 21/access
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

6: 0 AFT 21/access
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE

7: 0 BEF 257/openat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

8: 0 AFT 257/openat
 rax=0000000000000004

9: 0 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

10: 0 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

11: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

12: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BF30000

13: 0 BEF 3/close
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

14: 0 AFT 3/close
 rax=0000000000000000

15: 0 BEF 257/openat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

16: 0 AFT 257/openat
 rax=0000000000000004

17: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

18: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000340

19: 0 BEF 8/lseek
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

20: 0 AFT 8/lseek
 rax=0000000000000318

21: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

22: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000044

23: 0 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

24: 0 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

25: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

26: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BF2E000

27: 0 BEF 8/lseek
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

28: 0 AFT 8/lseek
 rax=0000000000000318

29: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

30: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000044

31: 0 BEF 8/lseek
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

32: 0 AFT 8/lseek
 rax=0000000000000360

33: 0 BEF 0/read
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

34: 0 AFT 0/read
 rax=0000000000000020

35: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

36: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BD68000

37: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

38: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

39: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

40: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BD8A000

41: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

42: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BED7000

43: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

44: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BF24000

45: 0 BEF 9/mmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

46: 0 AFT 9/mmap
 rax=00007FEE5BF2A000

47: 0 BEF 3/close
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

48: 0 AFT 3/close
 rax=0000000000000000

49: 0 BEF 158/arch_prctl
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

50: 0 AFT 158/arch_prctl
 rax=0000000000000000

51: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

52: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

53: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

54: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

55: 0 BEF 10/mprotect
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

56: 0 AFT 10/mprotect
 rax=0000000000000000

57: 0 BEF 11/munmap
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

58: 0 AFT 11/munmap
 rax=0000000000000000

59: 0 BEF 56/clone
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

60: 0 AFT 56/clone
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

pidfind: NEWPID ctl_xid=1 ctl_pid=0015006C/1376364
61: 1 AFT 56/clone
 rax=0000000000000000

62: 0 BEF 56/clone
 rax=000000000015006C

63: 0 AFT 39/getpid
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

64: 1 BEF 35/nanosleep
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

65: 0 BEF 39/getpid
 rax=000000000015006B

66: 0 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

67: 0 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

68: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

69: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F4D000

70: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

71: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F6E000

72: 0 AFT 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

73: 0 BEF 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F6E000

74: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

75: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=000000000000000F

76: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

77: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

78: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

79: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=0000000000000006

80: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

81: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

82: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

83: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=0000000000000006

84: 0 AFT 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

85: 0 BEF 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

86: 0 AFT 35/nanosleep
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

87: 1 AFT 35/nanosleep
 rax=0000000000000000

88: 1 BEF 39/getpid
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

89: 1 AFT 39/getpid
 rax=000000000015006C

90: 1 BEF 5/fstat
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

91: 1 AFT 5/fstat
 rax=0000000000000000

92: 1 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

93: 1 AFT 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F4D000

94: 1 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

95: 1 AFT 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F6E000

96: 1 BEF 12/brk
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

97: 1 AFT 12/brk
 rax=0000000000F6E000

98: 1 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

99: 1 AFT 1/write
 rax=000000000000000F

100: 1 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

101: 1 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

102: 1 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

103: 1 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

104: 1 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

105: 1 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000006

106: 1 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

107: 1 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000005

108: 1 BEF 1/write
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

109: 1 AFT 1/write
 rax=0000000000000006

110: 1 BEF 35/nanosleep
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

111: 0 BEF 35/nanosleep
 rax=0000000000000000

112: 0 AFT 61/wait4
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

113: 1 AFT 35/nanosleep
 rax=0000000000000000

114: 1 BEF 231/exit_group
 rax=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFDA

EXIT: 1 status=00000000

EXIT: 1 status=00000000
```

Comment: I have edited the code if you could please check again.
I have added PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE, I did not add ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0); because I believe ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL) already does that and PTRACE_CONT is not required, and changed to record child_pid, but im not getting the grandchild, any ideas on what else I can do?

Comment: @frazz I've updated my answer with the fix and additional code.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);` in your parent program.
- To let the parent trace its child, use `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);` within the child you are spawning.

(See listing_2 and listing_3 in [this link](https://pramode.net/articles/lfy/ptrace/pramode.html) for a simplified example.)

Comment: That works for a program that does not fork() itself, but my issue is a problem with fork() not being traced by the parent process